# Extracting data from a database but with different database versions

Tags: database

I am facing a problem with extracting data from a database. The problem is that I have more than one version of the database. Each version differs in the number of columns available and also the name (label) of columns may also change.

**For example:**
One version has column with the name `contact`, but with another version is `contact_name` (they represent the same information).

The question is how can I deal with such a situation where the column names can change from one database version to another. Also, if possible, reduce the need for changing my source code if more information (columns) has been added to the database.

I want to hear some suggestions before I start coding.

Comment: Is it not possible to bring the database schema in line with each other? Each change you make will be one hack on another :/

Comment: What you can do about this will largely depend on your programming language and other frameworks.  For example, some frameworks like Ruby on Rails want to use the exact names of the database columns as the object's properties, while others let you create a mapping table of column names to object attributes.  However, this seems like a very poor software engineering choice.  Most of the time, you want to have your database schema largely nailed down before you start to code.  Despite the fact that some frameworks let you do this, you will definitely have a big headache down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the databases have a look at implementing an abstraction layer between your code and your database:

> [Database abstraction layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) reduce the amount of work by providing a consistent API to the developer and hide the database specifics behind this interface as much as possible.

You can then develop without worrying about the underlying structure, and contain all of information about what columns to use in what database within this layer.

In practice, what you'd use would depend on what language you're using, what database you're using and how the application is designed.

Comment: The language am using is Java. and the database is sqlite.